# Android MediaPlayer setDataSource blocks until another MediaPlayer instance finishes preparing

Tags: android, media-player, blocking

I am having a MediaPlayer instance that is preparing a network stream. While it is still preparing I am allocating another MediaPlayer instance and trying to set the datasource to a local file. setDataSource method blocks until the first MediaPlayer instance finishes preparing. I only tested using the emulator. Do you have any ideas why this happens ? As far as I know the 2 MediaPlayer instances should behave independently.
Thank you.

I created a small test outside my application. This is the code of my onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.thebutton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("555555555555555");
            MediaPlayer pl2 = new MediaPlayer();
            System.out.println("6666666666666");
            try {
                pl2.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/Music/ABBA/Abba - Waterloo.mp3");
                System.out.println("777777777777");
                pl2.prepareAsync();
                System.out.println("888888888888");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    System.out.println("111111111111");
    MediaPlayer pl1 = new MediaPlayer();
    System.out.println("22222222222222");
    try {
        pl1.setDataSource("http://glb-stream14.streamserver.ch/1/rsc_it/aacp_64");
        System.out.println("3333333333333");
        pl1.prepareAsync();
        System.out.println("444444444444");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the log output:

```
12-28 14:59:57.478: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=net.selfip.imiklosik.tests/.MyActivity bnds=[2,155][58,214] }<br/>
12-28 14:59:57.707: INFO/System.out(342): 111111111111<br/>
12-28 14:59:57.737: INFO/System.out(342): 22222222222222<br/>
12-28 14:59:57.747: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('http://glb-stream14.streamserver.ch/1/rsc_it/aacp_64')<br/>
12-28 14:59:57.747: INFO/System.out(342): 3333333333333<br/>
12-28 14:59:57.787: INFO/System.out(342): 444444444444<br/>
12-28 14:59:58.048: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity net.selfip.imiklosik.tests/.MyActivity: 426 ms (total 426 ms)<br/>
12-28 15:00:05.338: INFO/System.out(342): 555555555555555<br/>
**12-28 15:00:05.338**: INFO/System.out(342): 6666666666666<br/>
**12-28 15:00:18.449**: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('/mnt/sdcard/Music/ABBA/Abba - Waterloo.mp3')<br/>
12-28 15:00:18.449: INFO/System.out(342): 777777777777<br/>
12-28 15:00:18.449: INFO/System.out(342): 888888888888<br/>
12-28 15:00:18.467: ERROR/MediaPlayer(342): error (1, -2147483648)<br/>
12-28 15:00:18.498: ERROR/MediaPlayer(342): Error (1,-2147483648)<br/>
```

The first bolded timestamp is after I pressed the button (right before the setDataSource call on the second player object).
The second bolded timestamp is after setDataSource method finished.
There is a 13 seconds difference, the time that the setDataSource method (called on a completely different MediaPlayer object, while the first MediaPlayer object was preparing - even with prepareAsync) was blocked.
Why is this happening ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

use [prepareAsync ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29) with the first one that get it stream from network since using `prepare()` will block your UI thread , so that the second MediaPlayer will wait until the first one finishes preparing.

Comment: you applied my answer in your code then edit the question with another error , every one will devote my answer .. why that !!!

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean here. What another error ? This is the error I as talking about earlier (setDataSource blocks until the first preparation ends). And I didn't "apply" your answer because in my program I was already using prepareAsync method. It's true, I forgot to state it. Besides, if I had been using prepare before then I couldn't have called setDatasource again because the UI would have been blocked. Maybe just from another thread, but then there wouldn't have been any blocking. Please be more expilicit.

Comment: I'm sorry, now I understand what you mean. But what alternative was there ? The only way I could post my new code was to edit my question. I didn't intend any devoting.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that if I use another network url (http://listen.radionomy.com/radio-mozart) which is an mp3 stream the problem disappears. setDataSource doesn't block any more. The original url was an aac stream that is not supported by API8 MediaPlayer. But still, setDataSource method called on another MediaPlayer shouldn't block in my opinion. Is this an Android bug ? Now I will have to address this situation when setDataSource blocks.